# Meteor Event: Children of list element

Tags: jquery, meteor, html-lists, meteor-blaze

I have the following

```
<template name="configs">
  <ul>
    {{#each config in configs}}
      <li>{{config.title}}
        <span>{{config.url}}</span>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>


Template.configs.events = {
 'click li': function(e) {
   Meteor.call('foo', $(e.target).children('span').html();, function(err, response) {
     });
  }
};
```

I would like to receive the "span"-text()-value after clicking on a list element. Unfortunately the actual approach always results in an empty object. Is there a special Meteor logic that I have to apply?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Template.configs.events = {

 'click li': function(e) {
   var txt =  e.target.textContent;
   Meteor.call('foo', txt, function(err, response) {
     });
  }
};
```

Comment: I found a solution. Thank you for your input though.